# python enforce type hints

Tags: python, generics

How do I use `enforce_typing` with `typing.Generic`?

basic usage of `enforce_typing` looks like this and works as expected,

```
from enforce_typing import enforce_types

@enforce_types
def bar(val : float) -> None:
    print(val)
    
bar(3.14) # PASS
bar('3.14') # TypeError: Expected type '<class 'float'>' for attribute 'val' but received type '<class 'str'>')
```

I'm trying to use enfore_typing with a generic class (templated). The following code results in `TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types`. How can I use enforce_typing with a templated class?

```
from enforce_typing import enforce_types
from typing import TypeVar, Generic
T = TypeVar('T')

class Foo(Generic[T]):
    @enforce_types
    def __init__(self, value: T) -> None:
        self.value = value

    @property
    def val(self) -> T:
        return self.value
    
foo = Foo[float](3.14)
```

Comment: So, this is not part of the standard library, and I've never heard of it before. I can find it on PyPi and it seems to have last released in 2019...

Comment: Looking at the source code, it seems like it is out of date: https://github.com/matchawine/python-enforce-typing/blob/master/enforce_typing/decorator.py (typing internals are shifting quicky, so using code that was written 3 years ago probably isn't going to work well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `enforce_typing` library ([source](https://github.com/matchawine/python-enforce-typing/blob/master/enforce_typing/decorator.py)) seems outdated.

Since Python 3.5, Python supports the [typing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#module-typing) library, that allows for type hints.

Using a type checker, such as [mypy](http://mypy-lang.org), you can check if typing hints are provided in all times (using the option `--strict`).

I recommend using Python version 3.5 or later, use the `typing` library and a type checker such as `mypy`.